# Why does I get <br /> in text when I apply nl2br() on the result of a json_decode?

Tags: php

I have a small issue. In my app, I have a place where user can enter data in several text area (store information) and it's all put in a json array, put in my database and I reuse it later to display it.

I apply nl2br() to get the new lines in the text area to be `<br />`. It works... but it isn't displayed as a newline, but as a plain `<br />` in my text.

Here is my code to display the json:

```
                    @foreach(json_decode($employer->stores) as $store)
                    <p>{{ nl2br($store) }}</p>
                    @endforeach
```

```
["asasdsadasasd\r\nasdasd","asdaasdaaaaaaaaas\r\nasdasdaaaaa"]
```

This get displayed:
`asasdsadasasd<br /> asdasd`

How to fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: The template engine you are using (which is it?) is probably escaping HTML. Its documentation will probably tell you how to disable that or what to do to render line breaks.

Comment: @FelixKling Damn, I feel stupid right now haha. Can you post this as an answer? I am using Blade. You can include that {!! $content !!} would be the right code to use in your answer.

Comment: you should never call nl2br on JSON code. You should instead extract values from the decoded JSON object and then call NL2BR on that instead. this may seem tedious, but a lot of JSON has new lines to make the markup more readable.

Comment: @S.Imp that’s what I did, might not seem obvious from my code but I extract the data from JSON and then go over it in my foreach.